# ArcPad 10.2 Command bar & Quick Access Menu

Tags: vbscript, arcpad

I am interested in making the Quick Access menu and Command Bar not available/visible for my users. The Quick Access Menu is prompted by the little icon on the bottom right of the tab bar seen here:

[image]

The Command Bar is only visible while making edits but I have the tools it provides already in a custom draw tool bar and I believe it to be unnecessary. Also, it provides a menu icon much like the Quick Access Menu that I do not want end users messing with. For reference the bar is as such:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I asked this question was because accessing the Quick access menu was causing a change in the ArcPadPrefs.APX. I still have not found a way to make these menus/bar disappear into the abyss, however I have solved the issue of my end users modifying the preference file. Right click the preference file and check "read only" prevents changes from being made from within arcpad or at least that is what I have observed. I hope this information is of at least some help to the people whom upvoted this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I had to develop with ArcPad but I remember you can set ArcPad to open with your custom toolbars and standard ones hidden. You had to fiddle around the the [default configuration file](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpadstudio/10.0/help/index.html#/Default_configuration_files/01q00000003z000000/GUID-1EF440D7-A0C2-464B-AA25-C12859E5A76C/) in ArcStudio.